# setTimeOut and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was playing around with learning some JavaScript and this small code didn't work for me.  If I take out the `setTimeout` function, the hover works again.  
Why doesn't the hover work?

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/1n8gqeom/

```js
setTimeout(
function(){
$(".div").css("background","blue");}, 100);
```

```css
.div{
  background:black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  
}
.div:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".div").css("background","blue");}, 100);`

With this line of code, you are adding inline style to the `.div`, so it has higher specificity.

Try something like this:

```js
setTimeout(
  function() {
    $(".div").addClass('someClass');
  }, 100);
```

```css
.div {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.div:hover {
  background: red;
}
.someClass {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

css priority。 inline style > class style, so, cover

```
.div:hover{
  background:red !important;
}
```